# Browser loads "Â" character in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

When the webpage opens and the resource are downloaded from the webserver, chrome is showing Â in the resource file which shouldn't be there.
After a hard refresh (ctrl + F5) chrome is retrieving the file without the signs and the webpage loads correctly.

[image]

The characters are not there in the source code however.
[image]

The character set in the `<head>` is set to *UTF-8*

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

It is quite anoying the user always needs to do a hard refresh so I would like to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you notice they're all before spaces? And in the two places in your source you have a · (an actual space) they arent there? Try going through the source and rewriting those spaces

Comment: Add this meta tag
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`